# Why getDerivedStateFromProps is called after setState?

Tags: reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

React introduced new static method `getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` which is called before every render method, but why? Calling it after prop change makes sense to me but after `setState` it doesn't, maybe I am missing something.

I was creating a `datePicker` Component according to my company requirement, in the component date is controlled from the prop. I have the following state in the component.

```
selectedDate: number;
selectedMonth: number;
selectedYear: number;
currentMonth: number;
currentYear: number;
view: string;
```

selected represents selected date which is derived from date prop and `currentMonth` and `currentYear` represents month and year in the current calendar view.

If `date` from prop changes `selected*`, `currentMonth` and `currentYear` should be changed accordingly. For that, I am using `getDerivedStateFromProps` but let say user clicks on Month name which will switch calendar view to month (instead of dates name of the month will be shown), the function updates the `currentMonth` for this using setState, but date the prop is same as before (containing previous month) which should, but `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called and currentMonth is again as same as before instead of changing.

Right I creating an extra variable in `state` to track if `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called due to `setState` but I don't think that's the right way.

Either I am doing something wrong or missing something or `getDerivedStateFromProps` should not be called after `setState`. Probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps isn't called on setState call. Its when the parent re-renders that the childs getDerivedStateFromProps is called and when the component mounts. A reproducible demo or a relevant code might help in pointing out the mistake. Check this demo which proves that setState doesn't trigger getDerivedStateFromProps https://codesandbox.io/s/k94z83mz6r

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps is called before every render method, it was used to call only on prop change once but they changed that in a release probably 16.4

Can you check the sandbox again, I have updated the react and react-dom version

Comment: Yeah, you are right, in the latest version it is called before every re-render

Comment: So did you find a workaround for this. It seems to be useless, to call it on every rerender, as it breaks setState functionality, and it is impossible to distinguish between state change and props change. Really annoying...

Comment: Hi @tylik, I am setting state from props in the constructor and using componentDidUpdate to update state from props if required.

Comment: @mukuljainx hi
although officially they don't recommend this approach, it seems to be the only way to go. Thanks fro response!

Comment: @tylik, Yup, have that in mind :D. I will soon refactor the whole component with right approach few other things and will surely share it as an answer, right now I just don't have the time for it, many other tasks in the queue.

Answer (score 11):

The way `getDerivedStateFromProps` hook works whenever the **new props**, **setState**, and **forceUpdate** is being received.

In the version of `16.3`, React is not affecting `getDerivedStateFromProps` whenever the `setState` is being used. But they improved it in the version starting with  `16.4`, so whenever the `setState` is being called the `getDerivedStateFromProps` is being hooked.

Here's extracted image from [React lifecycle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/):

### **16.3**

[image]

### **^16.4**

[image]

---

So, it's up to you when to hook the `getDerivedStateFromProps` by checking props and states properly. Here's an example:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps (props, state) {
  // check your condition when it should run?
  if(props.currentMonth != state.currentMonth) {
    return {
      currentMonth: state.currentMonth
    }
  }
  // otherwise, don't do anything
  else {
   return null
  }
}
```

Comment: Improved it in version 16.4? It's more like they broke it in version 16.4. The new version is useless.

Comment: It's improvement. What you think is useless?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar because the method does more than what it says it does now, e.g. it should be renamed to `getDerivedStateFromPropsStateForcedUpdates`

Answer (score 11):

I did something like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        expanded: props.expanded,
        ownUpdate: false
    }
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.ownUpdate) {
        return {
            expanded: state.expanded,
            ownUpdate: false
        };
    } else if (props.expanded !== state.expanded) {
        return {
            expanded: props.expanded
        };
    }
    return null;
}

toggle() {
    this.props.onAftePress(this.state.expanded, this.props.index);
    this.setState({
        expanded: !this.state.expanded,
        ownUpdate: true
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution for this in place of setting ownUpdate:true?

Comment: This does not look safe to me. React can batch rendering so it is possible for getDerivedStateFromProps to be called because your state changed **and** the props changed. In this particular case you're better off storing a prevExpanded state from the props.expanded value and comparing with that to see if the expanded prop has changed.

Answer (score 3):

I also got that issue. So I set another variable to check is that prop received for the first time.

```
this.state={flag:true}
```

In **getderivedstatefromprops**

```
static getderivedstatefromprops(props, state){
   if(props.<*propName*> && flag){
      return({ props.<*propName*>, flag:false})
   }
}
```

if you want to use multiple props values you need to set your if statements (or any other logic) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you have the answer in your question itself. "which is called before every render method". Whenever you do a `setState` the `render` method will be called.

I would suggest that you lift the state variables `currentMonth` and `currentYear` to the parent component and pass them as prop along with other three. You can also pass the change handler as prop and call it from the child.

on initial `render` - 
`currentMonth` and `currentYear` can be set to `null`, so that you can have the logic for showing default stuff. When someone chicks on month name, you can call the `changeHandler` from parent which will pass the new prop. Now in `getderivedstatefromprops` you no longer have `currentMonth` and `currentYear` as `null so you know that the month has changed.

Answer (score 0):

For this case (updating the state based on props change), use:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // don't forget to compare props
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

`componentDidUpdate` will get called after each update (due to props changes / state changes). so you should check if the prop is changed (by `this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID`).

Answer (score 0):

The below seemed to work well for me, and is pretty general.

In constructor:

```
this.state = {
    props,
    // other stuff
}
```

In gDSFP:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, state) {
    if (state.props !== newProps)
        // Compute and return new state relevant to property change
    else
        return state;
}
```

A bit of experimentation confirms that "state" is no longer automatically the old state, but in this hook instance is the newly set state in combination with the existing props.  I imagine the hook was added so as not to have to directly call gDSFP to repeat complex state evolutions dependent on the props, e.g.

```
this.setState(ClassName.getDerivedStateFromProps(this.props, newState))
```

The problem is that this is not quite a breaking change, but may result in subtle inefficiencies if old code needlessly does a lot of computation in getDerivedStateFromProps. I just discovered, for instance, that a complex object was being triply constructed, once for real, and two more times just because of this new hook.